# Access an service in jboss through JNDI (RMI?)

Tags: java, jboss, rmi, jndi

I need to make an service in jboss and access it through JNDI on the client side.
I have been playing around a bit with JNDI and made something like this on the client side:

```
import javax.naming.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        App app = new App();
        app.setSysProp();
        app.setObject();
        app.getObject();
    }

    public void setSysProp() {
        System.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "127.0.0.1:1099");
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    }

    public void setObject() throws NamingException {
        Context context = new InitialContext();

        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        obj.setName("NameOfMyObject");

        context.bind("obj", obj);
    }

    public void getObject() throws NamingException {
        Context context = new InitialContext();

        MyObject obj = (MyObject) context.lookup("obj");

        System.out.println(obj.getName());  
    }
}
```

This only binds and object to jndi on the client side and later retrieves it.

Now what i want is to bind a similar object on the server side (Jboss 4.2.3) and through it make some operations on the server. How can this be done? Ive read that something named RMI should be used in this case but what exactly is that and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ive read that something named RMI should be used in this case but what exactly is that and how to use it?

RMI is the Java standar API for Remote Method Invocation. It allows you execute a method on a object that reside in other Java Virtual Machine. Take in mind that you don't need a application server like JBoss to communicate with a remote java object. This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/) provides a simple tutorial.(notice that JBoss or any other app server is not mentioned)

> I need to make an service in jboss and access it through JNDI on the client side.

This is a different thing. Although, JBoss (as a Java EE specification compliant server) use RMI extensively, you don't need understand how this API works. What you need is to create a server side component called [EJB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans#Remoting.2Fdistributed_execution) which allows you to have a service running on a server.

> How can this be done?

There are hundred of tutorials about how to implement a basic EJB. Choose one compatible with your JBoss version due to some implementation details often change from one version to another.
You will also find that EJB specification has been evolving. With JBoss 4.2.3 and Java 5 you can start with EJB 3.0 which is easier than the previous one (2.1)